# Blender Pro Lighting Skies add-on not enable error

Tags: 3d, blender

I have downloaded and installed the **Pro Lighting Skies Ultimate** add-on in Blender. It installed
correctly with no issues but when I  try to enable using the checkbox near it on the addon menu it showed an error.

The error showed in Terminal is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Blend\2.93\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 386, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\pro_lighting_skies_ultimate\__init__.py", line 44, in register
    environment_lighting.register()
  File "C:\Users\Sri\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\pro_lighting_skies_ultimate\environment_lighting.py", line 3433, in register
    bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass 'prolightingSkiesPreferencePanel'
```

I HAVE ALREADY REMOVED AND RE-INSTALLED IT TO Fix this error but It doesn't work

What to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The latest Blender versions apparently are causing conflict. Downgrading my Blender version to 2.90 fixed it for me.